# The SSID of my WiFi is not appearing in the list of neighbor networks

Tags: router, wireless-router

I cannot connect the laptop to my home WiFi network neither trough the local list of wifi networks or manually (setup the SSID, security protocol and password). All neighbour WiFis are accessible except my.
But connection through the cable between the router and laptop is working perfect.
The laptop is brand new and there is no restriction by MAC in the router, except the setup of the router.
I tried to reinstall the WiFi drivers, but the result is without changes - same problem persists.

```
Lenovo M30, OS Win 8 Pro 64b 
TP-Link WR1043ND
Firmware Version: 3.13.13 Build 130325 Rel.34960n
Hardware Version: WR1043ND v1 00000000
```

The result of the shell command "netsh wlan show networks" shows 11 networks, but not mine.

Comment: What settings (and particularly, what channel) have you set your AP on ?

Comment: Did you by chance disable SSID broadcast in your router?

Comment: Channel 13, the broadcast is enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As this is a 2.4Ghz only AP and a modern laptop this is only one likely culprit.

Some regions allow CH1 to C11, others allow C1 to CH13, if the router operates in CH 12 or C13 but the client is regioned for CH11 max the SSID will be "invisible" as the radio will not scan for beacons in the required frequency.

Change the TP link to use a fixed channel bellow CH10(in case of wide bands) and it should appear within 20 seconds.

Comment: Probably, the channel issue is the problem, however my old Lenovo 570 is working with 13th channel. I will try 10th ch.

Comment: After change of the channel from 13 to 10 the issue was solved, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

reset router to factory settings and use the wizard to setup. don't change anything outside the wizard and keep to the standard SSID.

Answer (score -1):

I restarted my router and everything workes like before.